# HTML JavaScript- how to empty contents of div which holds local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

How can i empty the contents of div=history. This div is used to display local storage, once the 'clear button is clicked i would like that page to clear. Can anyone advise me?

```
<button onclick="click_button_clear()">Clear</button>

<div id="history"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function click_button_clear() {
    window.localStorage.clear(); 
}
```

sorted

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.

Comment: once i click on the 'clear' button, my HTML page which holds local storage is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

```
function click_button_clear() {
    jQuery("#history").empty(); 
}
```

If you can make use of jQuery, otherwise:

```
function click_button_clear() {
    document.getElementById(history).innerHTML = ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below in Jquery:

```
function click_button_clear()
{ 
    $('#history').html('');
}
```